# LED indicators for HVAC (24 VAC)

Tags: led, current-limiting

I have an HVAC which I would like to add some status indicators to.  I have some tri color LEDs, but could use suggestions as to how to utilize those LEDs.

What I am figuring is that I need a diode to protect the LED, and supply it DC, and then a current limiting resistor to limit the current from the rectified 24 VAC.

I have a bag of a thousand or so 1N4001 diodes, which I figured I might use.

Is there a better way?

Comment: A half wave rectifier will give you 24/pi = ~7.5VDC which is quite useful for driving  tri-color (RGB) LEDs with low currents (e.g. 5-10mA for indicators).

Comment: I think you mean 24 * pi, which is considerably more than 7.5V :)

Answer (score 1):

Better still is a simple series diode plus current-limit resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgBA6i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There can be advantages to putting a reverse-polarity diode in parallel with a LED when that LED is being fed from an AC source but there are usually specific reasons for doing so.

The problem with a single series resistor feeding a LED with a reverse-polarity diode in parallel is that the resistor is dissipating power for most of the entire AC half-cycle.

If you use a series resistor plus a diode also in series, the resistor is dissipating power for only half of the time.  This reduces the power by half and either lets you use a smaller resistor **OR** the resistor runs cooler.

You can add a resistor in parallel with the LED if you want to trim the turn-on voltage of the LED.  This can help stop the LED from illuminating with small leakage currents.

Answer (score 0):

A single diode in parallel with the LED, but reversed so it conducts in the opposite direction, will protect the LED from large reverse voltages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIrE95.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But the result can flicker noticeably when run on AC.

An alternative, if you have plenty of diodes, is just to make a bridge rectifier, and rectify the AC into DC.  Without a capacitor, the LED will still flicker to some extent, but it will be a lot better.

Comment: Flicker is not an issue on an indicator light.  But at 30Hz it would be more like a strobe.